# PostgreSQL unused tables for our database, query issue?

Tags: postgresql, performance

Is there a way to find out the old and unused tables in the database to delete them?
We are using a PostgreSQL database!.

Comment: What you mean 'unused' tables? Empty tables or not queried tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming an "unused table" means it has zero rows.

Run the following query to list all the tables with zero row count:

```
select table_name, pg_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name)) 
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public'
order by 2
```

Replace `public` if you are using a different schema.

Comment: If the schema is not on your `search_path`, you'll have to modify the query.